# Mozilla Firefox crash in Debian

Tags: firefox, debian

I have Seeed  ReSpeaker v2.0 and it comes with Mozilla already installed. It is not starting and it gave me this error:

[image]

I tried different browsers and all not starting

I also tried to reinstall Mozilla and clear and same result

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading (`apt-get upgrade`), so I downgraded Firefox:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr=52.9.0esr-1~deb9u1
```

Then I was able to run the demo install and use Firefox to register the device with Amazon.

Hope this helps.